# How do I make a typebinder only valid for a specific content type?

Tags: playframework

I am writing a json typebinder to convert json to a Java object of class Foo.  But I only want it to be used when the content type is application/json, so that I accept multiple content types without having to define separates methods and use the @As annotation.  I basically am looking for a way to define a @Global TypeBinder that is only used when the content-type is application/json.

```java
@Global
public class JsonObjectBinder implements TypeBinder<Foo> {
    @Override
    public Object bind(String name, Annotation[] annotations, String value,
            Class actualClass, Type genericType) throws Exception {
        return new Gson().fromJson(value, Foo.class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All binders are stored in a `Map<Class, TypeBinder>` and at the runtime the binder is picked from the map according the type to be bound. If you define more than one binder for a type only the one will be used - that one which was lucky to be the last to be registered.

So you have no other option to control the selection of binder.
You can see it for yourself in the class play.data.binding.Binder.

*If you want to have different binders you can use different intermediate objects e.g. `JsonFoo` and `XmlFoo` with appropriate binders. What's more you can define `JsonFoo` and `XmlFoo` as subclasses of `Foo`.*